# ffmpeg convert vp9 video to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube

I am using this command

```
ffmpeg -i $youtubeUrl -strict -2 -c copy output.mp4
```

(with $youtubeUrl generated by youtube-dl) to download this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnCJhq-JOck

I can't play the downloaded video though on Ubuntu or Windows (for a problem of vp09 codec) and I have to convert the video to webm and then back to mp4 to be able to play it:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -strict experimental output_2.webm
ffmpeg -i output_2.webm -strict 2 output_3.mp4
```

This happens only with *some* youtube videos, not all of them.

Is there a way to download all youtube videos in a readable format with only one command line, without having to convert to webm?

Comment: Download the best MP4 format using youtube-dl. VP9 in MP4 is not standard.

Comment: I was using this solution of downloading with ffmpeg because I actually download pieces of the video with the options -ss and -to, not the whole video. For very large videos it saves me a lot of time.

Comment: Ok, get the URL of the best MP4/AVC format, then.